# Sharepoint 2007: Display current time

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I need to add the current running time into the default.master page. The time should auto-update.
I don't have access to add code except for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really sharepoint question. You need a Jquery/javascript solution here. The following script will show the time on the web page. You need to reexecute it as per your interval to refresh it if you want.

```
 1: <script language="javascript">
   2: function getTime() {
   3:     var dTime = new Date();
   4:     var hours = dTime.getHours();
   5:     var minute = dTime.getMinutes();
   6:     var period = "AM";
   7:     if (hours > 12) {
   8:         period = "PM"
   9:     }
  10:     else {
  11:         period = "AM";
  12:     }
  13:     hours = ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours)
  14:     return hours + ":" + minute + " " + period
  15: }
  16: </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get it to autoexecute?